# Can Xcode 4.6 run on Yosemite?

Tags: xcode4.6

I'm working on a project using Xcode 4.6 running on Maverick.

I wanted to upgrade to Yosemite, can the Xcode 4.6 still running properly in Yosemite?

Comment: I'm pretty sure not.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. I get the following crash report when launching Xcode 4.3.6

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'delegateClass' of extension 'Xcode.IDEiPhoneOrganizer.MenuDefinition.Screenshots' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport'
>
> UserInfo: {
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x4014c4520 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode_4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEiPhoneSupport, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode_4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode_4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x400310540 \"The bundle \U201cIDEiPhoneSupport\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";